# RabbitMQ Connection Failure after adding google auth dependency

Tags: amqp, google-auth-library

After adding the following dependency

```
compile "com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:'1.23.0'"
```

to `build.gradle` all integration tests related to RabbitMQ failed with a connection error:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2089)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.lambda$execute$13(RabbitTemplate.java:2051)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2050)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1009)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1068)
    at com.mttnow.message.delivery.common.tenant.TenantEventIntegrationTest.Tenant event with delivery config should notify listeners(TenantEventIntegrationTest.groovy:37)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1137)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1087)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:526)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:473)
    ... 11 more
```

I suppose this dependency adds some filters of authorization over all connections/requests. I don't know how to resolve this issue.
I need this dependency to migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1.